# How to turn a shapefile into a dbf?

Tags: database, shapefile, qgis, dbf

I want to turn a set of files .shp, .shx .dbf that I created after creating a layer with QGIS, and I want to turn that into a 'table file' meaning a file that I can open up with Excel. I know that dbf files are good for this, as they are table database files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to what I wanted was:

Open .shp layer with QGIS,
Right click layer & Save As.. ,
Select .csv , 
at the geometry column select AS_XY ,
Save.

and you get a full featured table with all attributes concerning a .csv file

Answer (score 0):

You need to open .dbf file in excel. You can drag and drop the file (in windows explorer) in to excel sheet, and the dbf file will open as an excel table. You can now save this file as excel. But this process is irreversible, that means any changes you do in this excel table won't be reflected in the original .dbf file.

Comment: I don't want to turn a .dbf into excel. I want to turn a .shp into an a dbf.

Comment: Any .shp file always comes with a .dbf file. In fact any .shp file is a set of 5 or 6 different file types. One of them is .dbf. You can find this by opening the folder containing the .shp file you are referring to. The .dbf file will have exactly same name as .shp file.

Comment: the problem is, when I open the dbf file in the excel I don't see a column with any spatial features I may have added through QGIS to thart shapefile. How can I see a Table with spatial data too?

Comment: When I import shapefile into postgresql with shapefile .dbf loader I get a full table with all data available. How can I see that without using the importer?